# bash script for service montioring with email alert and prevent repeated alerts

Tags: bash

I have a following script scheduled to run every 5 minute that checks for two services and if it found any service status down,it sends email. Its working ok.

But the issue is I want it to send UP alert as well when service goes up. I can add line to send email but it repeats the up alert. how can i add UP alert function but it should send alert just one time (like it do for down alert)

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep "mysql" > /dev/null
then
    echo "MYSQL Running"
    rm -f /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent
else
    echo "ALERT: mysqld Stopped."
    if [ ! -f /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent ]; then
echo "Sending MYSQL DOWN Email..."
echo "DOWN ALERT! sending email" > /var/run/.mysql_mail_sent

    fi
fi

if pgrep "radiusd" > /dev/null
then
    echo "radiusd Running"
    rm -f /var/run/.radiusd_mail_sent
else
    echo "ALERT: RADIUSD Stopped"
    if [ ! -f /var/run/.radiusd_mail_sent ]; then
echo "RADIUSD DOWN: Sending Email."
echo "DOWN ALERT! sending email" > /var/run/.radiusd_mail_sent
    fi
fi
```

Comment: please refer to my previous answer from this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245345/script-for-rhel-6-to-check-the-status-of-cpu-and-send-mail-if-cpu-utilization

Answer (score -1):

Ok I finally made it. BASH is quicker and doesn't requires any 3rd part tool.
[updated 4:43pm]

```
#!/bin/bash
# Scheduled Script to check linux service status after every 5 minutes.
# If found stopped, send sms or email Alerts, but donot repeat it untill next status change.
# Syed Jahanzaib


# Run script with service name like
# ./status.sh mysqld


# Check if no service name is given
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
echo No service name have been provided.
echo Usage exmaple:
echo
echo -e "./status.sh mysqld"
echo
fi

DATE=`date`
COMPANY="MYISP"


SERVICE1="$1"
SUBJECT="ALERT: $SERVICE1 is Down..."
STATUS_HOLDER="/tmp/$SERVICE1_STATUS_HOLDER.txt"

# KANNEL Gateway Info
KANNELURL="127.0.0.1:13013"
KANNELID="kannel"
KANNELPASS="password"
CELL1="0333xxxxxx"

# SMS Msgs test
MSG_UP="$COMPANY Info: $SERVICE1 is now UP @ $DATE"
MSG_DOWN="$COMPANY Alert: $SERVICE1 is now DOWN @ $DATE"

touch $STATUS_HOLDER

for SRVCHK in $SERVICE1
do
        PID=$(pgrep $SERVICE1)
        if [ "$PID" == "" ]; then
                echo "$SRVCHK is down"
                if  [ $(grep -c "$SRVCHK" "$STATUS_HOLDER") -eq 0 ]; then
                        echo "ALERT: $SERVICE1 is down at $(date) / SENDING SMS ...."
            echo "$MSG_DOWN" > /tmp/$SERVICE1_down.sms
# Sending DOWN SMS via KANNEL
cat /tmp/$SERVICE1_up.sms | curl "http://$KANNELURL/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=$KANNELID&password=$KANNELPASS&to=$CELL1" -G --data-urlencode text@-
                        echo "$SRVCHK" >> $STATUS_HOLDER
                fi
        else
                echo -e "$SRVCHK is alive and its PID are as follows...\n$PID"
                if  [ $(grep -c "$SRVCHK" "$STATUS_HOLDER") -eq 1 ]; then
                        echo "INFO ALERT : $SERVICE1 is UP at $(date) / SENDING SMS ...."
            echo "$MSG_UP" > /tmp/$SERVICE1_up.sms
# Sending UP SMS via KANNEL
cat /tmp/$SERVICE1_up.sms | curl "http://$KANNELURL/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=$KANNELID&password=$KANNELPASS&to=$CELL1" -G --data-urlencode text@-
                        sed -i "/$SRVCHK/d" "$STATUS_HOLDER"
                fi
        fi
done
```

Comment: `bash` is quicker than what?

Comment: @mikeserv I meant to say BASH is fun :)